# redux toolkit doesn't work properly in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

its my first app on React native,i want to use redux toolkit persist, but I get  ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined, js engine: hermes
LOG  {"numberHouse": 0}.

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

import setHouse from './setHouse';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  version:1
};

const reducer = combineReducers({
    house:setHouse
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
});  my store.js

import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'house',
  initialState: { numberHouse: 0 },
  reducers: {
    setHouse: (state,action) => {
        state.numberHouse = action.payload
    }
  },
});

export const { setHouse } = counterSlice.actions;
export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

my setHouse.jsx

here is my index.js file:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import { Stack,useRouter } from "expo-router";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import persistStore from "redux-persist/es/persistStore";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";

import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 

import Unit from "../pages/Home";
import Houses from "../pages/Houses";
import { store } from "../redux/store";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const persistor = persistStore(store)

function Tabs() {
  const router = useRouter()
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator  screenOptions={
        ({ route,navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ color,focused,size}) =>{
                let iconName;
                if(route.name==='Home'){
                  focused ? iconName='home' : iconName='home-outline';
                  return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color}/>
                } else if (route.name==='Houses'){
                  return <MaterialIcons name="hotel" size={size} color={color}/>
                }
            },
            headerShown: false,
            headerTitle:''
        })
    }>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Unit} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Houses" component={Houses} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
    
      <SafeAreaView style={{zIndex:4,height:'100%'}}>
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown:false}}/>
          <NavigationContainer style={{zIndex:4,height:'100%'}} independent={true}>
              <Tabs />
          </NavigationContainer>
      </SafeAreaView>
    
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

and here is components where I try to send a data:

```
import { View,Text,Image,TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import setHouse from "../redux/setHouse";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export default function HouseBox(props){
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        dispatch(
            setHouse(props.houseNumber),
            type='house'
        );
    };
    const data = useSelector(state=>state.house)
    console.log(data)

    return(
        <View style={{width:315,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
            <View style={{width:'100%',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',gap:20}}>

                <Image style={{width:'100%',height:400,borderRadius:20}} resizeMode="cover" source={props.img}/> 
                <View style={{padding:10,paddingTop:30,paddingBottom:30,borderWidth:1,borderRadius:20,gap:3,justifyContent:'space-between',backgroundColor:'white',width:'100%',height:380}}>
                    <Text style={{fontWeight:600,fontSize:30}}>House {props.houseNumber}</Text>
                    <Text style={{fontWeight:300,fontSize:18}}>{props.houseText}</Text>
                    <Image style={{width:300,position:'relative',top:-20}} resizeMode="contain" source={require('../public/logoss.png')}/>
                    <View style={{width:'83%',borderLeftWidth: 1,gap:10,paddingLeft:20,position:'relative',left:30,top:-35}}>
                        <Text style={{fontWeight:300,fontSize:18}}>Price</Text>
                        <Text style={{fontWeight:300,fontSize:18}}>{props.price}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{borderRadius:20,marginTop:20,position:'relative',top:-30}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleClick} style={{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',borderRadius:20}}>
                            <View style={{width:'96%',borderRadius:15}}>
                                <Text style={{backgroundColor:'black',color:'white',width:'100%',textAlign:'center',borderRadius:20,padding:10,fontWeight:300,fontSize:18}}>More Info</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>

            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

when I click 'More Info',I get  LOG  {"numberHouse": 0}
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined, js engine: hermes
LOG  {"numberHouse": 0}. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `type='house'`, and especially remove the comma. That's not the JavaScript syntax you think it is. The comma means "throw away the result from before", so your code

```js
dispatch(
  setHouse(props.houseNumber),
  type = "house"
);
```

is actually equivalent to

```js
setHouse(props.houseNumber);
dispatch((type = "house"));
```

which will probably already error because `type` is not a declared variable, but if that wouldn't error, it would be equivalent to

```js
setHouse(props.houseNumber);
type = "house";
dispatch("house");
```

It should be

```js
dispatch(setHouse(props.houseNumber));
```

instead.

---

Also, your import here is wrong:

```
import setHouse from "../redux/setHouse";
```

This is equivalent to

```
import { default as setHouse } from "../redux/setHouse";
```

which means that you import the **reducer** and call it `setHouse`. That's fine (albeit very confusing) for your `combineReducers` call, as you actually want a reducer there, but for your `dispatch` call, you should not try to dispatch the result of calling a reducer, but you should dispatch the result of an action creator.

The import in that file would need to be

```
import { setHouse } from "../redux/setHouse";
```

as that would import the *named export with the name `setHouse`* from that file, not the default export.

Comment: so it doesn't solve my problem,what I suppose to do to solve ? its still gives me the same error

Comment: Oh, you also have a wrong import. Editing.